# How to iterate over xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an xml stack like this;

```
<translations>
  <message1>A message</message1>
  <message2>A second message</message2>
</translations>
```

Using xslt and the for-each method, how can I get the name (message1, message2) and values (A message, A second message) as key/value pairs?]

EDIT:

My desired output would be used to generate a javascript object e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var t = {
    <xsl:value-of select="name()" /> : '<xsl:value-of select="." />'
  }
</script>
```

Obviously the above doesn't work but that was my initial thinking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <xsl:text>var t = {</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="translations/*">

            <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), ' : ')" />
            <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
            <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
    </script>
</xsl:template>
```

Output:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var t = {message1 : 'A message',
message2 : 'A second message'
}</script>
```

Comment: This almost works for me, however the 'var t = {' and '};' need to be placed outside the loop. Also how can I determine if I am at the last node so that I can omit a comma (,)?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
<xsl:template match="translations">
  <xsl:for-each select="*">
    <kvp key="{name()}" value="{.}"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```